# Retrieving associated elements based on ID in entity query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have an entity query which groups the number of property reviews to a property. However im having some trouble with the query to pull the rest of the data  on the property based on its propertyID. Thanks!

Example Results:

```
|PropertyID | NumOfReviews |     StreetAddress     |    City    |
      1             14             1600 Speaker St.        Miami
```

Query:

```
var query1 = from r in db.Reviews
                    group r by r.propertyID into g
                    select new
                    {
                        propertyID = g.Key,
                        numofReviews = g.Count()
                        //Get Rest of data
                    };
```

Property Model:

```
 public partial class Property
{        
    public int propertyID { get; set; }
    public string streetaddress { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zip { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string route { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Review Model:

```
  public partial class Review
{
    public int reviewID { get; set; }
    public int propertyID { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public string review { get; set; }    
    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you come at it from the opposite direction?

```
var query = from p in db.Properties
            select new {
                propertyId = p.PropertyId,
                numofReviews = p.Reviews.Count()
                //Grab remaining properties off of the p variable that you need
            };
```

Comment: Not sure how i missed such a simple workaround. Thanks!